# How to add Disclosure button to Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can I render the Disclosure button graphic with it not being a button.  I want to add the image to the custom rendered cell, but am not sure how to get the image.

How do I render the image alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [Photoshop template file](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/?p=1628) with most of the iPhone UI elements. You can extract the image and use it for a custom cell view.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively dirty workaround would be: make an app that has the button, run it on the device. Take a screenshot (press lock/menu buttons at the same time). Email that picture to yourself. Using a photoeditor, crop/edit as needed. voila. you've got the image.