# How to Add Disclosure Triangle to Gradient Button?

Tags: cocoa

I have a Gradient Button with the NSAction template. In Apple's apps, this is almost never the way in which configuration options are represented. Rather, the NSAction glyph is used in conjunction with the Disclosure Triangle glyph, in the same Gradient Button. For instance, in System Preferences > Network:

[image: NSAction template joined with Disclosure Triangle in the same Gradient Button]

I can't figure out how to add the Disclosure Triangle glyph. How would I do this?

Also, yes, I have already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128510/how-to-add-disclosure-button-to-custom-uitableviewcell). I want to know if there is any **official** capacity in which to do this, either using Interface Builder, or programmatically with Swift, as is recommended by the Apple [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ControlsButtons.html):

> When possible, use system-provided images, such as the Action and the Add images, because their meaning is familiar to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work to just set the type to Pull Down while the style is set to Gradient:

[image: IB Attributes inspector screenshot]